# Error: term has fewer unique covariate combinations than specified maximum degrees of freedom

Tags: r, smoothing

I'm trying to smooth this mortality data, but I get this error when I try to call *smooth.demogdata(...)*. I don't have a lot of years to work with (just 2004-2014), and only ages 1-11. I need to have smoothed mortality data to be able to run the Lee-Carter models.

```
> US.demog.age = demogdata(US_rates.age, US_counts.age, ages = 1:11, 
               years = 2004:2014, type="mortality", name="Total", label="US")
> smooth.age = smooth.demogdata(US.demog.age)
Error in smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) : 
  A term has fewer unique covariate combinations than specified maximum degrees of freedom
```

The matrix data I have for the demography data call are as follows:

```
> US_counts.age
 135618, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
 150988, 125213, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
 144797, 144686, 117643, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
 145921, 138953, 136791, 110374, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
 146350, 139452, 131145, 128469, 103897, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
 159301, 139080, 130705, 122500, 120655, 97922, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
 169750, 151355, 130195, 121681, 114789, 113711, 92623, 0, 0, 0, 0
 166925, 158914, 142749, 122450, 114941, 108932, 108085, 88116, 0, 0, 0
 174177, 158635, 150225, 134504, 116111, 109365, 103898, 103520, 84283, 0, 0
 174938, 165078, 149825, 141967, 127656, 110712, 104557, 99706, 99568, 80944, 0
 169517, 165777, 155530, 141601, 134922, 121745, 105924, 100205, 95836, 95749, 77716



> US_rates.age
0.0034287484, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0.0031989297, 0.0036178352, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0.0029213312, 0.0032415023, 0.0036636264, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0.0022957628, 0.0028930646, 0.0031873442, 0.0035334408, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0.0017902289, 0.0023162092, 0.0027298029, 0.0030513198, 0.0033013465, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0.0015254142, 0.0017328156, 0.0022187369, 0.0025224490, 0.0028925449, 0.0029717530, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0.0011310751, 0.0014733573, 0.0016052844, 0.0020052432, 0.0023434301, 0.0025855018, 0.0027207065, 0, 0, 0, 0
0.0008926164, 0.0011389808, 0.0013730394, 0.0014373214, 0.0018531246, 0.0021389491, 0.0022297266, 0.0024286168, 0, 0, 0
0.0004994919, 0.0008068837, 0.0009452488, 0.0011300779, 0.0012057428, 0.0015818589, 0.0017805925, 0.0019513138, 0.0020882028, 0, 0
0.0003029645, 0.0004422152, 0.0006407475, 0.0007466524, 0.0007676882, 0.0008761471, 0.0012815976, 0.0014442461, 0.0014362044, 0.0016184028, 0
0.0001415787, 0.0002050948, 0.0002829036, 0.0003954774, 0.0003705845, 0.0004517639, 0.0004342736, 0.0006885884, 0.0008138904, 0.0008772938, 0.0009264502
```

The data is tracking cohorts over time, which is why there are zeroes in the upper right half of both matrices, since no previous information on the cohorts is available, so those are listed as 0s, but it is those 0s and the actual available data that need to be smoothed.

Is there any way I can get the smooth.demogdata function to work? I know I saw something about changing the default knot values from 10 to something lower, but I wasn't able to find that again.

Comment: 0 doesn't seem like a good idea to use for missing data.  NA would be the better value to put there.

Comment: I just tried to replace the 0 values with NA values for the 3 possible combinations of the 2 matrices and I still get the same error.
That is, I tried: 0 rates to NA with 0 counts, 0 rates with NA counts, and NA rates with NA counts.

Comment: I wasn't saying it would fix your problem - just saying that it's a bad way to represent "missing"

Comment: Ah, yes. Would you suppose that manually reducing the degrees of freedom value for the smoothing function would solve this problem?
I recall reading something about some s(...) function where one could change the knots value using s(..., k=??). I'm not sure how I would go about this with the matrix data, though.

Comment: `smooth.demogdata` takes an argument for the number of *knots*: `k = 30` is the default, which you can change to suit your needs.